# Type families - Couldn't match type

Tags: haskell, type-families

I'm baffled by this compiler error message I'm getting. The functions addAgent and withAgent have similar type signatures and similar implementations, so I don't understand why addAgent compiles but withAgent doesn't. Thank you in advance for any help!

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Monad.State (StateT, execStateT, gets, modify)

class AgentDatabase d where
  type Elem d
  addAgent :: Elem d -> StateT d IO ()
  withAgent :: 
     (Elem d -> StateT d IO (Elem d)) -> String -> StateT d IO ()

data SimpleUniverse d = SimpleUniverse {
    agentDB :: d
    -- plus other fields
  }

-- I want the methods of class AgentDatabase to "penetrate" through
-- the outer wrapper of SimpleUniverse and operate on the agentDB field.
instance (AgentDatabase d) => 
    AgentDatabase (SimpleUniverse d) where
  type Elem (SimpleUniverse d) = Elem d

  -- When addAgent is invoked on a SimpleUniverse, apply it to the
  -- agentDB field inside.
  addAgent a = do
    db <- gets agentDB
    db' <- liftIO $ execStateT (addAgent a) db
    modify (\u -> u { agentDB=db' } )

  -- When withAgent is invoked on a SimpleUniverse, apply it to the
  -- agentDB field inside.
  withAgent program name = do
    db <- gets agentDB
    db' <- liftIO $ execStateT (withAgent program name) db -- line 33
    modify (\u -> u { agentDB=db' } )
```

The error message I get is...

```
amy3.hs:33:11:
    Couldn't match type `d' with `SimpleUniverse d'
      `d' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at amy3.hs:19:25
    When using functional dependencies to combine
      Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState s (StateT s m),
        arising from the dependency `m -> s'
        in the instance declaration in `Control.Monad.State.Class'
      Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState
        (SimpleUniverse (SimpleUniverse d)) (StateT (SimpleUniverse d) IO),
        arising from a use of `gets' at amy3.hs:33:11-14
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: db <- gets agentDB
    In the expression:
      do { db <- gets agentDB;
           db' <- liftIO $ execStateT (withAgent program name) db;
           modify (\ u -> u {agentDB = db'}) }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: You need to fix `program` when you pass it to the inner `withAgent`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In the `AgentDatabase` class, the `program` argument will have the type `Elem d -> StateT d IO (Elem d)`. And when I declare `SimpleUniverse` to be an instance of `AgentDatabase`, I declare that `SimpleUniverse` uses the same `Elem` type as the database (`agentDB`) that it contains. So doesn't `program` already have the correct type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`program` has type

```
Elem (SimpleUniverse d) -> StateT (SimpleUniverse  d) IO (Elem (SimpleUniverse d))
```

which indeed simplifies, but to

```
Elem d -> StateT (SimpleUniverse d) IO (Elem d)
```

and the inner `withAgent` takes a program of type

```
Elem d -> StateT d IO (Elem d)
```

To fix that, this function will help:

```
stateMap :: Monad m => (s -> t) -> (t -> s) -> StateT s m a -> StateT t m a
stateMap f g (StateT h) = StateT $ liftM (fmap f) . h . g
```

Comment: Ah, I understand the problem now, thank you. But now I can't figure out how to solve the problem. I'm trying to write a function with the signature `f :: StateT (SimpleUniverse d) IO (Elem d) -> StateT d IO (Elem d)`, but I can't figure out how to code it.

Comment: I added the `stateMap` function, hope that helps.